How do I convert HOTP counter value to unsigned char*?
I am now facing issues implementing HOTP using HMAC-SHA1. I am not sure how do I convert the "Counter" from int to unsigned char* for HMAC hashing.
I call hmac_6_digit_totp() as below
unsigned char key[33] = "00000000000000000000000000000000";
std::cout << hmac_6_digit_totp(hmac_sha1, key, 32, 0) << '\n';

part of source code:
template<typename T, typename U>
T time_counter(std::chrono::duration<T> step, std::chrono::time_point<U> time_point) {
  std::chrono::duration seconds_since_epoch = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(time_point.time_since_epoch());
  return seconds_since_epoch.count() / std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(step).count();
}
template int time_counter<int>(std::chrono::duration<int> step, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point);
template long long time_counter<long long>(std::chrono::duration<long long> step, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> time_point);
template int time_counter<int>(std::chrono::duration<int> step, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> time_point);
template long long time_counter<long long>(std::chrono::duration<long long> step, std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> time_point);

unsigned int byte_array_to_int(const unsigned char *bytes, size_t bytes_size) {
  if (bytes_size < 20) return 0;
  int offset = bytes[bytes_size - 1] & 0x0F;
  int value = (bytes[offset] & 0x7F) << 24 | (bytes[offset+1] & 0xFF) << 16 | (bytes[offset+2] & 0xFF) << 8 | (bytes[offset+3] & 0xFF);
  std::cout << value << '\n'; // debugging
  return value;
}

std::string hmac_6_digit_totp(const std::function<int(const unsigned char*, int, const unsigned char*, size_t, unsigned char*, unsigned int)> &method, const unsigned char *key, int key_len, int time_count_offset) {
  long long time_count = time_counter(std::chrono::seconds(30), std::chrono::system_clock::now());
  if (time_count < 0) return "-1";
  time_count += time_count_offset;

// code here was written by ChatGPT
  unsigned char data[8];
  for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--) {
    data[i] = static_cast<unsigned char>(time_count & 0xFF);
    time_count >>= 8;
  }
// code above was written by ChatGPT

  unsigned int md_size = EVP_MAX_MD_SIZE;
  unsigned char md_buffer[md_size];

  if (method(key, key_len, data, sizeof(data), md_buffer, md_size) < 0) return "-3";
  
  for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) { // for debugging
    std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(2) << (unsigned int)md_buffer[i] << ' ';
  }
  std::cout << '\n';

  char output[7];
  snprintf(output, 7, "%06u", byte_array_to_int(md_buffer, sizeof(md_buffer)) % 1000000);

  return std::string(output);
}

int hmac_sha1(const unsigned char *key, int key_size, const unsigned char *data, size_t data_size, unsigned char *md_buffer, unsigned int md_size) {
  if (md_size < 20) return -2;
  if (!HMAC(EVP_sha1(), key, key_size, data, data_size, md_buffer, &md_size)) return -1;
  return 20;
}


I have double checked that hmac_sha1() and byte_array_to_int() is very likely to be correct using online test data. Therefore I think it is the data (counter) fed to hmac_sha1() that caused this issue.
counter value: 57782654 (code used: std::cout << time_counter(std::chrono::seconds(30), std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';)
hex output in hmac_6_digit_totp(): fa 31 1e d1 ea ce c6 3e 28 db 8b 65 0e dd d8 a8 6f 84 a3 76

Could you clarify which piece of code you think is incorrect?

The code labelled 'written by ChatGPT' is a perfectly reasonable way to convert an 8 byte integer to a byte array, so if that's not working for you maybe you need some different kind of conversion.

From section 5.2 of rfc 4226: The Key (K), the Counter (C), and Data values are hashed high-order byte first. This is still unclear, but I take it to mean that the counter is treated as a little-endian 64-bit integer.

@john Maybe it is the logic that is not correct. I have already checked that hmac_sha1() and byte_array_to_int() is correct; thus I think we can narrow down to the logic of generating data[] (the part ChatGPT wrote) However, I cannot find resources about that online

@PresidentJamesK.Polk Isn't little-endian 64-bit integer the logic ChatGPT used?

To be honest, I always get confused by endian issues. I was just quoting the RFC to try to add clarity. You could always try the other way and see if it works.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk I have been trying for 3 hours, still no luck. But thank you very much!

@Yakk-AdamNevraumont I am only trying to understand the logic behind HOTP. I will not use my own version in other projects.

I’m voting to close this question because  AI generated content is banned from stack overflow https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned

Don't use AI generated stuff on stackoverflow, discussing AI generated content is a waste of everyone's time (ChatGPT really doesn't know a thing about correct C++ coding)
